# Scraping the video url of a jWplayer stream

Tags: javascript, php, web-crawler, screen-scraping, jwplayer

Programs like jDownloader directly and automatically detect where the video url is hidden in the pasted websites code(mostly javascript since the most of them use jWplayer) and can even do that when the site wants you to do something first(like wait 10 sec. and look at the ads -> then user needs to click specific button and stream starts)

I wonder if its possible to do that in PHP?

For example:
You paste the url(i used a streamcloud video) in your script and the script does all the things for you(wait 10 sec. and click the button) and then throws a callback with the wanted url to you.

I found some good php scrapers(almost everybody said i should use python for this) that do a very good job but when it comes to the point where the script should do something on the other server(wait and click) i cant figure out how to do it or even google for the right things.

I hope someone can help me figure out how to come to my destination.

Comment: You can't scrapping is reliable only when there is no click needed you can't beat ajax by php-curl as much i know

Comment: ok, so what should i do instead?